# Main thread blocking loading of admob rewarded ad

Tags: ios, swift, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, firebase-admob

Whenever I am calling `loadAd()` function either from `onAppear()` or with a button click, it's giving the error:

> Main thread blocked by synchronous property query on not-yet-loaded property (assetProperty_Tracks) for HTTP(S) asset. This could have been a problem if this asset were being read from a slow network.

> Main thread blocked by synchronous property query on not-yet-loaded property (NaturalSize) for HTTP(S) asset. This could have been a problem if this asset were being read from a slow network.

> Main thread blocked by synchronous property query on not-yet-loaded property (PreferredTransform) for HTTP(S) asset. This could have been a problem if this asset were being read from a slow network.

> Main thread blocked by synchronous property query on not-yet-loaded property (EstimatedDataRate) for HTTP(S) asset. This could have been a problem if this asset were being read from a slow network.

> Main thread blocked by synchronous property query on not-yet-loaded property (NominalFrameRate) for HTTP(S) asset. This could have been a problem if this asset were being read from a slow network.

Resulting in giving me "Ad wasn't loaded". Here is my `loadAd()`:

```swift
class AdCoordinator: NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate, ObservableObject {
  private var ad: GADRewardedAd?

  func loadAd() {
    GADRewardedAd.load(
      withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313", request: GADRequest()
    ) { ad, error in
      if let error = error {
        return print("Failed to load ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }

      self.ad = ad
        self.ad?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
    }
  }

  func presentAd(from viewController: UIViewController) {
    guard let fullScreenAd = ad else {
      return print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }

      fullScreenAd.present(fromRootViewController: viewController, userDidEarnRewardHandler: didEarnedReward) // didEarnedReward prints "reward earned"
  }
}
```

The ad unit ID here is from Google's documentation.

Comment: same problem occurs on me +1, i also tried in another app, it's occuring the same problem, https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/vWFWu6XLraA
this is also another thread, hope they fix